# How to change the value of hidden input field before submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a Feedburner subscription form with two buttons, one for daily news and one for weekly news. The question is how to change the value of hidden input field with name *'uri'* before submitting? My solution doesn't work.

This is what I try to use:

```
<form id="feedburner" action="https://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify"
    method="post" target="popupwindow">
    <p>
        <input autocomplete="off" value="Enter your email…"
            onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter your email…';}"
            onfocus="if (this.value == 'Enter your email…') {this.value = '';}"
            type="text" name="email"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="uri"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="loc" value="en_US"/>
    </p>

    <input type="submit" value="Daily" onsubmit="document.getElementsByName('uri').value = 'androidinfodaily'; window.open('https://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=androidinfodaily', 'popupwindow'); return true" checked> 

    <input type="submit" value="Weekly" onsubmit="document.getElementsByName('uri').value = 'androidinfoweekly'; window.open('https://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=androidinfoweekly', 'popupwindow'); return true">

</form>
```

---

**Solved**

I have fixed my code and now it works. This is the final variant:

```
<form id="feedburner" action="https://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify"
    method="post" target="popupwindow">
    <p>
        <input autocomplete="off" value="Enter your email…"
            onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter your email…';}"
            onfocus="if (this.value == 'Enter your email…') {this.value = '';}"
            type="text" name="email"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="uri" />
        <input type="hidden" name="loc" value="en_US"/>
    </p>

    <input type="submit" value="Daily" onclick="document.getElementsByName('uri')[0].value = 'androidinfodaily'; window.open('https://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=androidinfodaily', 'popupwindow'); return true"> 

    <input type="submit" value="Weekly" onclick="document.getElementsByName('uri')[0].value = 'androidinfoweekly'; window.open('https://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=androidinfoweekly', 'popupwindow'); return true">

</form>
```

Answer (score 5):

The [submit event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit) is fired on the form element, not on submit button, so use [click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) handlers

> Note that submit is fired only on the form element, not the button or
>   submit input. (Forms are submitted, not buttons.)

```
<form id="feedburner" action="https://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify"
    method="post" target="popupwindow">
    <p>
        <input autocomplete="off" value="Enter your email…"
            onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter your email…';}"
            onfocus="if (this.value == 'Enter your email…') {this.value = '';}"
            type="text" name="email"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="uri"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="loc" value="en_US"/>
    </p>

    <input type="submit" value="Daily" onclick="document.getElementsByName('uri')[0].value = 'androidinfodaily'; window.open('https://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=androidinfodaily', 'popupwindow'); return true" checked> 

    <input type="submit" value="Weekly" onclick="document.getElementsByName('uri')[0].value = 'androidinfoweekly'; window.open('https://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=androidinfoweekly', 'popupwindow'); return true">

</form>
```

---

Also it will be better to speprate the script to a function like

```
<form id="feedburner" action="https://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify" method="post" target="popupwindow">
    <p>
        <input autocomplete="off" value="Enter your email…" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter your email…';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Enter your email…') {this.value = '';}" type="text" name="email" />
        <input type="hidden" name="uri" />
        <input type="hidden" name="loc" value="en_US" />
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Daily" onclick="return beforeSubmit('androidinfodaily')" checked />
    <input type="submit" value="Weekly" onclick="return beforeSubmit('androidinfoweekly')" />
</form>
```

then

```
function beforeSubmit(type) {
    document.getElementsByName('uri')[0].value = type;
    window.open('https://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=' + type, 'popupwindow');
    return true
}
```

Comment: Also it should be `document.getElementsByName('uri')[0].value` as `getElementsByName` returns a collection

Answer (score 2):

You can have click event handler for button and change type of button to `type="button"` so that it will not submit the form directly. Inside click handler assign balue to `uri` input and then submit the form.

HTML:

```
<form id="feedburner" action="https://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify"
    method="post" target="popupwindow">
    <p>
        <input autocomplete="off" value="Enter your email…"
            onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter your email…';}"
            onfocus="if (this.value == 'Enter your email…') {this.value = '';}"
            type="text" name="email"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="uri"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="loc" value="en_US"/>
    </p>

    <input type="button" value="Daily" id="daily"> 

    <input type="button" value="Weekly" id="weekly">

</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
   $('#daily').click(function(){
      $('input[name="uri"]').val('androidinfodaily');
      window.open('https://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=androidinfodaily', 'popupwindow');
      //submit form
      $('#feedburner').submit();
   });

   $('#weekly').click(function(){
    $('input[name="uri"]').val('androidinfodaily');
      window.open('https://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=androidinfoweekly', 'popupwindow');
      //submit form
      $('#feedburner').submit();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

do not forget `[0]` for the first element:

```
document.getElementsByName('uri')[0].value = 'androidinfodaily';
```